# Puzzle: whats the actual answer?

Tags: systems-of-equations, mathematical-physics, information-theory, entropy

I came across a viral brain test where given the below image it was asked to solve the puzzle. Most of the online communities are explaining that the answer will be 3. For example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iqa3gSDpSqo.

[image]

But to me its like impossible to solve. Because there are not enough information on how equations are constructed. For example some people might count the number of white points in the ball and result a different answer.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: This is literally just algebra. Three balls equals $18$, so one ball is $6$, for example.

Comment: where it was mentioned that the equation is made for the number? @BillWallis

Comment: @BillWallis the point is that the items in the bottom row aren't the same as the ones in the rows above.

Comment: @Arthur I did not notice that, my mistake.

Comment: @Arthur and BillWallis, there can be many different answers depending on what properties of the objects you consider to make the equations. So why people are considering only the black color points on the ball and the number of positive our in the clock etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematically, the question doesn't make sense. We can figure out that a clock at 3 is worth 3, and that a four-bladed fan is worth 4 (or possibly -3), but we have no information on what the clock at 2 or a three-bladed fan is worth.

If you want to go from mathematics to puzzles, then 3 is the most likely answer, but you can probably twist it to anything you'd like if you just try hard enough.

Comment: Even we have no information of what value the 3-black spot ball is worth for

Comment: @SazzadHissain The answer _is_ impossible to calculate. Which means we _have_ to guess. And if I had to guess, then I would guess that the thing that makes the top row footballs worth 6 each is probably the six black spots. The thing that makes the 3-clock worth 3 is probably the fact that it is at 3. And the four-bladed fan is probably worth 4 and not -3, and it's probably because of the fact that it has 4 blades. From all these guesses, we get the final answer of $3$. If you make other guesses, you get another answer. As long as your guesses are applied consistently, the answer isn't wrong.